# Would you be happy to welcome Whonix GNU/Linux users on tor.se?

Tags: discussion

Speaking as a maintainer of [Whonix GNU/Linux](https://www.whonix.org) which is a derivative of Debian GNU/Linux. Its focus is on anonymity/Tor.

Having a dedicated user support forum for Whonix and teaching Windows users who use a Debian derivative for the first time in a virtual machine the most basic things eats up a lot time. Therefore, for general Linux/Debian related questions, users are advised to use http://unix.stackexchange.com. (And unix.se is [happy](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1461/would-you-be-happy-to-welcome-whonix-gnu-linux-users-on-unix-se) with that.)

What about Whonix specific Tor questions? Such as "how do I configure obs3 bridges in Whonix 7?" Actually, answering this questions requires little difference from answering this question for system Tor / TBB. May I redirect users having such questions to tor.se?

([Previous discussion](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2013-June/028535.html) where the conclusion probably was "let's see how tor.se works out".)

I would myself [subscribe](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/subscribe-to-tags-via-emai/) to questions having the tag "whonix", and answer if no one else was faster and/or comment if I feel necessary.

whonix.org's own forum would stay open for questions not suited for the stackexchange format (opinion based, feedback, discussion).

Would you be happy to welcome Whonix GNU/Linux users on tor.se?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the questions are Tor related I would definitely welcome those here on Tor.SE. Tor.SE was made for users, developers and researchers of Tor, so Whonix users should fit in one of those categories.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to bring up questions like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97758/whonix-openvpn-setup?noredirect=1) which was recently migrated from Unix.SE or [this one](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/686/whats-preventing-ifenslave-from-bonding-multiple-openvpn-through-tor-tunnels-in) which I migrated *to* Unix.SE a few days ago.

I might have jumped the gun on this, but it strikes me that these kinds of questions aren't really "about Tor" instead they're about OpenVPN configuration (though it could be anything), with the caveat that "I'm using Whonix or Tails or putting it through the Tor network"... doesn't actually change the question, or make the answer any different which makes me think they'd get a better answer on Unix.SE for things like this. Any thoughts? Maybe we can compile some good/bad example Whonix questions? I'd start with the following (I've also made it CW, feel free to edit/discuss):

**Good questions**

- How do I configure software X to use Tor in Whonix?
- How do I fix leaks in software X in Whonix?

**Bad questions**

- How do I configure software X to use a VPN ontop of Tor? (Answer doesn't have anything to do with Tor, could equally apply to other software / isn't Tor specific)
- How do I configure feature X (that's not routing through Tor) in software Y in Tails/Whonix? (Nothing to do with Tor except that it's running on the same system)

Comment: I am fine with that.

Comment: I agree, a lot of the openvpn/whonix questions I've seen recently do not belong onto tor.se.c

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Except for the Debian/Linux questions going to unix.se, there arguably isn't much about Whonix that isn't Tor-related.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, the whonix questions are getting out of hand.  Only a fraction of them are Tor related.  Tor.SE isn't a general purpose "how to use my linux" forum.

Comment: Could you add some examples?